# Deleting Folders filled with files doesn't free up space immediately

Tags: c#, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, .net-core, ubuntu-server

When I delete a Folder using

```
DirectoryInfo.Delete(true)
```

the value for

```
DriveInfo.AvailableFreeSpace
```

stays nearly the same. For instance when I delete folders in a loop while checking `availablefreespace` I end up deleting gigabytes and gigabytes of data when it should have deleted less then a gigabyte.

```
//Delete in secondary storage
string secondaryRoot = Path.GetPathRoot(settings.SecondaryFeatureExtractDirectory);
DriveInfo secondaryDrive = new DriveInfo(secondaryRoot);
DirectoryInfo secondaryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(settings.SecondaryFeatureExtractDirectory);
while ((secondaryDrive.TotalSize - secondaryDrive.AvailableFreeSpace) / secondaryDrive.TotalSize * 100 < settings.DriveFreePercentage)
{
    logger.LogInformation("checkForCleanup before delete: {@Freespace}", secondaryDrive.AvailableFreeSpace);
    secondaryThresholdPassed = true;
    DirectoryInfo oldestDir = secondaryInfo.EnumerateDirectories().OrderBy(x => x.LastWriteTimeUtc).FirstOrDefault();
    if (oldestDir == null) break;
    oldestDir.Delete(true);
    logger.LogDebug("checkForCleanup deleted: {@DirectoryName}", oldestDir.FullName);
    logger.LogInformation("checkForCleanup after delete: {@Freespace}", secondaryDrive.AvailableFreeSpace);
    Thread.Sleep(1);

}
```

Is there any was around this using c# and dotnetcore?

Comment: This is going to use integer math so it it will either be 100 or 0.

Comment: @mwwhited Can you explain that? I dont understand how `(secondaryDrive.TotalSize - secondaryDrive.AvailableFreeSpace) / secondaryDrive.TotalSize * 100` would be constrained to either 0 or 100.

Comment: Those values are all integer values (really long... but same idea).  As such they will not have any decimal values.  think of `(100-90)/100`.  That would equal `.9` but being interger values the greatest integer is `0`

Comment: As it is, your result will always be `0` unless the drive is 100% filled.

Comment: Feeling kinda dumb now. Verifying that this is the fix.

Comment: Don't feel too dumb... integer math bites people in the ass all the time. Hopefully you won't forget next time :)  Just wait until you get floating point rounding errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the input values you are checking are integer types.  Integer math does not include decimal portions of a number.

```
var di = //new DriveInfo("c");
    new
    {
        TotalSize = 255471906816L,
        AvailableFreeSpace = 125059747840L
    };

var ps = ((di.TotalSize - di.AvailableFreeSpace) / di.TotalSize) * 100;
Console.WriteLine(ps);  // 0
var ps2 = (int)((((double)di.TotalSize - di.AvailableFreeSpace) / di.TotalSize) * 100d);
Console.WriteLine(ps2);  // 51
```